# semicolumn does not suppress output before comment in ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In ipython notebook, I find that

```
1+1;
```

does not produce output, as expected. However, if I add a comment:

```
1+1; #this produces output
```

it produces output. I know that I can suppress output by adding an assignment:

```
_=1+1 #this produces no output
```

I can live with this if it comes to that, but it's much uglier than the semicolon, and inconsistent with the rest of my code. 
Is there a way to restore the output-suppressing properties of the semicolon when a comment is present on the same line? In my application, the comment must live on the same line as the code.